# php preg_match image address which is bagin as letter

Tags: php, preg-match

I want to get all the image address which is a letter.
I use this...

```
<?php
$str = <<<EOT
image/20110331_121.jpg
../image/20110330_132.jpg
http://www.site.com/image/20110330_098.jpg
EOT;
$image = preg_match('#^[a-zA-Z](.*)\/.(jpg)$#i',$str);
print_r($image);// I want get a echo image/20110331_121.jpg
?>
```

Comment: first : int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
If you want "matches" items try preg_match("..", $str, $image);

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was the `\/` right before the `.jpg` without any placeholder. You could try this:

```
 $image = preg_match('#^[a-z]\w+/\w+[.](jpg)$#im',$str);
```

And you also forgot the `#m` modifier to apply `^` and `$` against multiple lines.

Comment: right, @mario, this also echo a `http` head image address, and I want to get only `image/20110331_121.jpg` which is no `http` head and bigan as `a-z`. thanks.